# Are purchasing questions Life Hacks?

Tags: discussion

I am having a healthy discussion over my question ["What ways are there to maximize Gift Card values at Grocery Stores?"](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/3632/2090), I want to improve it and also better understand the purpose of LifeHacks so I can ask better/concise questions in the future that are beneficial.

I have read through quite a few questions here on Meta but I am now not even sure if my Lifehack is approriate here or not.  Do questions dealing with purchases amount to a Life Hack? is there another exchange better suited?

I was also told that my question & answer might only pertain to a local entity and because it is not a wide spread possability maybe its not a life hack, but if the site goes broad like that then there are many questions here that might not be possible in other localities/countries right, just because a solutions includes an item that is not available in say Burundi or Iceland...

Comment: You raise a good point; I think the answer is "no," but I don't have the time to write up a proper answer at the moment. Obviously, my opinion is not binding ;-) ....thanks for taking your question here, and asking in a respectful manner; that's something you don't always see when someone's wondering why their question was put on hold, many take it personally (*whyy??*). Belated welcome to LH :)

Comment: @BrianH the question looks very broad, and nobody can judge if an answer is wrong or right. Gift cards are so different, and in one place you can get extra value for gift cards, on other place you can get nothing. It is very dependent on the authority issuing these gift cards.Their policy can be changing very fast and an answer that is true today may not be true tommorow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We value your question and answer, even if it may not feel like this at the moment. Here on SE we have the goal to have very high value content. It is sometimes hard to have the content one posts being put on hold or criticized as your post was. I think that your situation is quite lifehacky, yet it will most likely not be a good fit for our format. To fit in here it must be both, a lifehack AND a good Q&A. So, after thinking about your question I feel that your question will be hard to keep. But I sure hope you will still stick around here.

Comment: Looking at the closing reasons I think that you should improve your question based on that and then try for reopening. Your question could be indeed a viable Life Hack. Some suggestions are to include a condensed list of the Gift Card policies of your Store and then show us policies of the card you hold. Since Gift Cards can vary, I think that just saying gift card is to confusing. But also listing a long a list of policies is confusing so make the list as small as possible. I hope this helped and I hope to see around!

Answer (score 9):

What is a "purchasing question?" Is that a name for things? I'm not familiar.

Let's look at your question instead:

- Is there a specific problem to be solved?
- Are you looking for a solution that differs from the one you would customarily use? Why?

After reading your question, I can't answer that. Can you?

Comment: is the term wrong? I am thinking that this question being placed here in Meta is pertinent towards buying, purchaing or any monetary exchnage that could be considered a life hack.  Of course these are fleeting at times, which means thay could come and go as quickly as the sale at the store does.

Comment: A question about purchasing things then? I don't know if it's worth considering them a category; so far, we just have yours. Let's figure out whether that one is a viable question before we try to extrapolate.

Comment: thank you shog9, good point, appreciate it.